# Getting an error that says } is expected after the first console read line. what should i do?

Tags: c#

I'm new to this any pointers would be helpful thanks..

```
        int salary = 4000;
        if (salary >= 4000)
            Console.WriteLine(salary);
        Console.ReadLine();


        else
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum+salary+requirement+not+met");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Without curly braces, the only line associated with your if statement is `Console.WriteLine(salary);`.  So, you have an if statement, a separate statement, and then an `else`, which isn't paired with anything.  Taking a look at some examples or a textbook should help you get a better handle on the syntax.  This is pretty fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are technically optional if the statement following is a one liner, however it's a best practice to always use braces due to the situation you have. The current flow of yours is (with braces):

```
int salary = 4000;
if (salary >= 4000)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(salary)
    }
Console.ReadLine();
else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum+salary+requirement+not+met");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

As you can see your `else` statement is not paired to its required `if` statement.

The proper format for this would have been

```
int salary = 4000;
if (salary >= 4000)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(salary)
    Console.ReadLine();
    }    
else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum+salary+requirement+not+met");
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

There can be no other statements in between an `if/else` set. So, as a reminder, always use curly braces!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add extra info, if you are going to perform a `Console.ReadLine()` no matter the result of the `if` and `else`, then you better use it outside the brackets.

```
int salary = 4000;
if (salary >= 4000)
{
    Console.WriteLine(salary);
}    
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum+salary+requirement+not+met");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

That way you can skip using brackets and your code will still work

```
int salary = 4000;

if (salary >= 4000)
    Console.WriteLine(salary);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum+salary+requirement+not+met");

Console.ReadLine();
```